# After change navigation bar height, related constraint doesn't update

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have navigation controller in my project. I want set its height based on view controller's main view height.**If I could set this in IB then I don't face with issues, but I didn't find a way.** So I use the following command in ViewDidAppear of my Navigation Controller class.

```
self.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height * 0.05)
```

I also have another view controller that use this navigation controller and have another child view inside it named ViewTop. Top of ViewTop equals to bottom of TopLayoutGuide. Because I have navigation bar,in real its top set to bottom of navigation bar.

Before I use the above command, ViewTop's top is equal to bottom of navigation bar correctly.
[image: sample without problem]

The problem occurs when navigation bar height changed via the above command. The top of ViewTop doesn't update to bottom of navigation bar. It seems that this change in height of navigation bar played after constraints calculations.

[image: sample with problem]

Also use above command in viewWillLayoutSubviews and viewDidLayoutSubviews of my Navigation Controller class with no success. I didn't set any other constraints in code and just used IB.

[image: StoryBoard ScreenShot]

What Can I do?

Comment: you are breaking all constraint calculations if you manipulate frames by hand.

Comment: I'd use auto layout, but in spite of that, *where* is this line of code? Hopefully not in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Try calling `layoutIfNeeded` on the view which does not update.

Comment: @luk2302 If you have better way for this purpose explain it please.

Comment: @dfd I use it in ViewDidApear as I said.

Comment: @Nef10 I called it. But same as before.

Comment: Ok. Putting things you've said together, along with your code: (1) `viewDidLoad` is too early for the OS to guarantee to have frames. (2) If you are using constraints - something you haven't shown any code but is in your title - you are doing things wrong, as @luk2302 is telling you. (3) Please, show us your **constraints** (both in code and IB) along with how your **frames** - which won't work nicely - are defined. (4) Finally, try using `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead. (On that last comment, any questions, learn the lifecycle of how a view is presented.)

Comment: I edited my question.